# Why is else showing up as a syntax error in this simple code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So heres my code, im trying to make it so that if the username or the password are wrong it will say immediately which one is wrong and not pass, but i cannot figure out why ELSE is showing up as a syntax error: (edit: somehow the first line didn't show up)

```
username = input("Write the username:")
password = input("Write the password:")
if username == "Toby":
    pass
else:
    print("The username was wrong.")
if password == "Traveler":
    pass
else:
    print("The password was wrong.")
print("Password and username were correct!")
```

Comment: The indentation is off.

Answer (score 4):

From your code snippet, it looks like your indentations are not aligned.

Make sure you use 4 spaces in order to tell the interpreter you are now in an if/else statement.

```
if condition:
    if_logic()
else:
    else_logic()
```

Comment: According to PEP8, always use 4 spaces as indetation, so please remove the tab suggestion.

Comment: Consider to remove the suggestion altogether since the solution is *not* to use any tabs/spaces for ``else``. Only the respective blocks must be indented.

Comment: Noticed and changed.. although most IDEs interpret tab as 4 spaces, no?

Answer (score 2):

Check the indentation erros,

```
password = input("Write the password:")
username = input("Write the username:")
if username == "Toby":
    pass
else:
    print("The username was wrong.")
if password == "Traveler":
    pass
else:
    print("The password was wrong.")
print("Password and username were correct!")
```